# How do I properly install cfgrib and eccodes?

Tags: python, python-xarray, cfgrib, eccodes

I'm trying to run this code on my Mac: https://github.com/EWolffWX/MRMS_Derecho_Composites

When I run it, I get this error `ValueError: unrecognized engine cfgrib must be one of: ['netcdf4', 'h5netcdf', 'scipy', 'gini', 'pydap', 'store', 'zarr']` from this line of code:

```
ds = xr.open_dataset(filepath, engine="cfgrib")
```

I've tried every solution I could find online, and nothing is working. I've tried both `conda install eccodes` and `conda install -c conda-forge eccodes` to install the eccodes library, but neither have worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install cfgrib in addition to Xarray:

```
conda install -c conda-forge cfgrib
```

Comment: whats the best procedure here. Intall xarray first then followup with cfgrib or other way around?. I am facing problem too when converting grib to netcdf the problem mentioned says no engine çfgrib found on my machine